# Hover effect with jquery not changing to default background color

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Problem:** I want to add hover effect in the `tr` element but I have a background color assigned directly that is coming from the database. The hover effect works with jquery when I do a mouseover the color changes, but when I remove the mouse the background color doesn't go back to the previous.

I know this is not the best way to achieve this, if you have any ideia, please share it.

I already try adding a class to the `tr` element and with css define a hover effect to change the background color, but it didn't work.

```
<table id="waypointsTable" class="table table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Nº Pedido</th>
                        <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                        <th scope="col">Comentário</th>
                        <th scope="col">Promotor</th>
                        <th scope="col">Produtor CDM</th>
                        <th scope="col">Sala</th>
                        <th scope="col">Data Evento</th>
                        <th scope="col">Título</th>
                        <th scope="col">Data Criação</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <?php 
                        $requests = $app_R->getrequest($request_id, $user_id);

                        for($i=0; $i<count($requests); $i++){
                          $status = $app_R->getstatus($requests[$i]['Status_id']);
                          $status_color=$status[0]['color'];
                        echo'<tr class="clickable-row" style="background:'.$status_color.';" data-href="index.php?id='.$requests[$i]['Request_id'].'">';
                        echo'<th scope="row">'.$requests[$i]['Request_id'].'</th>';

                            echo '<td>'.$status[0]['name'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$status[0]['comment'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$requests[$i]['Promoter'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$requests[$i]['CDM_produtor'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$requests[$i]['Room'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$requests[$i]['Event_date'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$requests[$i]['Event_Title'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$requests[$i]['Creation_mod_date'].'</td>';
                            echo'</tr>';
                }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Jquery to hover effect

```
$('#waypointsTable tr').hover(function() {
     $(this).attr('style','background: yellow');
 }, function() {
     $(this).attr("style","background: '.$status_color.'");
 });
```

Comment: Instaed of trying with attribute you can do this by using css

Comment: @luis Where you declared variable `status_color` in js ?? You need to get this value in js also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your variable is a php variable, you cannot use it in your javascript like that - instead I would add it to a data attribute on the table row and then change the colour that way

**Update php to include data attribute**

```
echo'<tr class="clickable-row" style="background:'.$status_color.';" data-original-color="'.$status_color.'" data-href="index.php?id='.$requests[$i]['Request_id'].'">';
```

**Update js to use data attribute instead of php variable**

```
$('#waypointsTable tr').hover(function() {
   $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
}, function() {
   var original = $(this).data('original-color');
   $(this).css('background', original);
});
```

I have also changed the js to use `.css` instead of replacing the entire style attribute (in case something else needs to add styles to the tr)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

In javascript

```
 $('#waypointsTable tr').hover(function() {
     $(this).css('background' ,'yellow');
 }, function() {
     $(this).css("background',<?php echo $status_color; ?>);
 });
```

In CSS

```
<style>
 #waypointsTable tr:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Still hapends the same, when I do a mouse hover only changes to yellow, doesn't go back to the previous color.

Comment: please check you r status code once it should work....in your status code put some static data

Comment: My suggestion is to do this in css instead of javscript...it will be light weight

Comment: you forgot to add php tag please check the answer now

Comment: otherwise you can use css

Answer (score 0):

Try changing ' to " :

```
$(this).attr("style","background: " + $status_color + ";");
```

EDIT : I don't expect it was php.. duhh..

Remove ' then :

```
$(this).attr("style","background: $status_color;");
```

Comment: Wen I do a mouse hover only changes to yellow, doesn't go back to the previous color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should works. Also Get `status_color` in your jquery.

```
$(function () {
        $("#waypointsTable tr").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).attr("style","background: " + status_color);
        });
        $("#waypointsTable tr").mouseout(function () {
           $(this).css('background' ,'yellow');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR; Why use JavaScript?**

It's a bit hard to solve this problem without posting any current CSS styling. If you add the 'css tag' to your question, please to provide the CSS.

The `<tr>` element is the parent of `<td>` element. You can use the hover effect on the `<tr>` (see code-example) to change the background of the `<td>`. Because it's a child it will fill the space accordingly.

```css
tr:hover td {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table id="waypointsTable" class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Nº Pedido</th>
      <th scope="col">Estado</th>
      <th scope="col">Comentário</th>
      <th scope="col">Promotor</th>
      <th scope="col">Produtor CDM</th>
      <th scope="col">Sala</th>
      <th scope="col">Data Evento</th>
      <th scope="col">Título</th>
      <th scope="col">Data Criação</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable-row" style="background: blue">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>comment</td>
      <td>Promoter</td>
      <td>CDM productor</td>
      <td>Room</td>
      <td>Event date</td>
      <td>Event title</td>
      <td>Creation date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row" style="background: green">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>comment</td>
      <td>Promoter</td>
      <td>CDM productor</td>
      <td>Room</td>
      <td>Event date</td>
      <td>Event title</td>
      <td>Creation date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row" style="background: yellow">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>comment</td>
      <td>Promoter</td>
      <td>CDM productor</td>
      <td>Room</td>
      <td>Event date
      </td>
      <td>Event title</td>
      <td>Creation date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row" style="background: pink">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>comment</td>
      <td>Promoter</td>
      <td>CDM productor</td>
      <td>Room</td>
      <td>Event date</td>
      <td>Event title</td>
      <td>Creation date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row" style="background: pink">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>comment</td>
      <td>Promoter</td>
      <td>CDM productor</td>
      <td>Room
      </td>
      <td>Event date</td>
      <td>Event title</td>
      <td>Creation date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row" style="background: pink">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>comment</td>
      <td>Promoter</td>
      <td>CDM productor</td>
      <td>Room</td>
      <td>Event date</td>
      <td>Event title</td>
      <td>Creation date</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $('#waypointsTable tr').mouseOver(function() {
     $(this).style.color = "yellow";
 });

 $('#waypointsTable tr').mouseOut(function() {
     $(this).style.color = <?php echo $status_color; ?>;
 });
```

[W3School Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover_dom)